# What is the difference between "physical interaction" and "genetic interaction"?

Tags: database, gene

I searched sac1 in uniprot to know more about this gene. in [interaction](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P30619#interaction) I selected [this link](http://thebiogrid.org/32215) and there I see that this gene has some "physical interactions" and "genetic interactions". I am wondering that what is the difference between "physical interaction" and "genetic interaction"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Physical and genetic interactions are described in the [help wiki](http://wiki.thebiogrid.org/doku.php/experimental_systems), accessed via the top menu bar on the page you linked to.

*Physical interactions* refer to experiments where the gene product (protein) has been shown to physically interact with another protein, such as by co-immunoprecipitation, fluorescent staining, yeast two-hybrid system, etc.

*Genetic interactions* refer to experiments where changes in a certain gene reflect in changes to your gene of interest (or vice-versa) - dosage lethality, dosage rescue, synthetic haploinsufficiency, etc.